# Developing "Command Line" in .NET?

Tags: .net, command-line

Imagine a "search box" on the right top side of the UI Windows Application. When user types a desired action, a matching functionality is executed. Screen gets opened, or action gets performed.

For example: user types "create" and intellisence offered next word options "client"/"product", user picks "client", and "Create New Client" screen opens up.

So what I am looking for if there is a framework support for this. I assume that framework shall bind together text commands names, commands and show in intellisense. Same framework possibly could have been used in alternative "Command Line interface".

I recall Microsoft had some recent framework that helps to setup "command Line Interface" environmental. It is hard to search on web for this keywords, so relying on intelligent help from you guys. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered a Domain Specific Language? [This Code Project article is a good start](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/YourFirstDSL.aspx).

I'm not sure about the intellisense portion of your question, gut feeling is that it could be quite involved.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is useful.
So there are 2 alternatives:
1. Domain Specific Language
2. PowerShell Runtime

Answer (score 3):

You could look into hosting the PowerShell runtime inside your app and spare yourself a lot of work reinventing the wheel....

- [How to: Host the PowerShell Runtime](http://notgartner.wordpress.com/2008/02/23/how-to-host-the-powershell-runtime/)
- [Writing your own PowerShell hosting app](http://powershellstation.com/2009/10/12/writing-your-own-powershell-hosting-app-part-1-introduction/) (4 part blog post series)
- [Writing a Windows PowerShell Host Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me more like you're looking for a development environment for the programmer more than a specific underneath framework.

So with that said, Boo (http://boo.codehaus.org/) is great for developing .NET programs, but I'm not sure if it's what you want.